# I can't able to install ubuntu alongside with Win7 ..:

Tags: wubi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why can't I install Ubuntu or Wubi on a dynamic disk? (“The request isn't supported” from bcdedit.exe)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/179215/why-cant-i-install-ubuntu-or-wubi-on-a-dynamic-disk-the-request-isnt-suppor)

I was unable to install ubuntu 11.04 and 10.10 with WUBi, and also, I was unable to boot up my pc through 11.04 though I did it with Ubuntu 10.10 as a live session.
when I try to install ubuntu (both version) alongside with Win7 , following massage is appearing when extracting the kernal ,

Error executing command

> > command= c:\windows\sysnative\bcdedit.exe/set
> >     {d99017fa-e624-11e0-a90b-f90474903c3b} device partition= D:
> >     retval=1
> >     stdrr=An error has occurred setting the data
> >     The request is not supported.
> >     stdout=
> >     For more information please see the log file
> >     c:user\ p-\appdata\local\temp\wubi-10.10-revi97.log

please, I asking help from someone to overcome this matter..

Ps: I'm using 64-bit processor

Comment: Please provide the content of c:\user\p-\appdata\local\temp\wubi-10.10-revi97.log

Answer (score 1):

Usually that happens if you're trying to install on a dynamic 'disk'.

With Win7 now it offers to convert to dynamic disks when you already have 4 primary partitions and you try to create another. Unfortunately this process is not easily reversible and these partitions are not visible to linux as they're not in the MBR partition table.

In fact that error is not Wubi, it's Windows preventing you from booting directly from the dynamic partition. It would work if you picked C: but don't do this - running linux on a disk with dynamic partitions can lead to data loss (since they're not visible to Ubuntu).

Here's a thread where the poster converted from dynamic back to simple: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1868679