# Why can't I install Ubuntu or Wubi on a Windows Dynamic Disk?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows, system-installation

I've been trying to install 12.04 for a while now, I'm running on Windows 7 and I already made the partition (it's dynamic). I've tried booting from a disc and also the Windows installer. I haven't tried used any repair-boot programs or anything. Every time I tried to load from either, I get an error:

```
command=C:\windows\sysnative\bcdedit.exe /set {03f9077f-661f-11e1-845a-d08b36406c3d} device partition=U;

retval=1

stderr=An error has occured setting the element data.
The request isn't supported

stdout=
```

Then after that, it makes a log file with information that I don't understand.

If it is simply due to the fact of it being a dynamic partition, someone please help.
If it is more extensive, anyone with details on *possible* solutions or definite ones please express them.

Comment: Can't really help you solving this, but remember that you always have an option to install Ubuntu using bootable media.

Comment: Are you running this as System Administrator in MS Windows?

`Exception: Error executing command
>>command=C:\Windows\System32\bcdedit.exe /set {2708afc0-9ffa-11e1-bc51-d167219ffa25} device partition=E:
>>retval=1
>>stderr=An error has occurred setting the element data.
The request is not supported.`  could be interpreted as you don't do that.

Comment: you mean installing it using virtualBox or virtual PC ?

Comment: when you say that are you asking if i'm trying to run it as a virtual machine? if so, i am not. i got it to load if i used my C:\ drive but it doesn't install. how can i make a partition and it will actually recognize it at start up?

Answer (score 16):

> Note: Wubi is Ubuntu installed onto a Windows drive via the Windows installer

#### Neither Ubuntu nor Wubi will boot from a dynamic disk

Neither Ubuntu's bootloader GRUB nor Wubi's bootloader GRUB4DOS can recognize a Microsoft dynamic disk/volume/partition (SFS), and so they cannot boot from it; there is no sense in installing either when you won't be able to boot.

#### You have three options:

- Convert the dynamic disk to basic *(backup all data first!)*, after which you can install Wubi or dual-boot with Ubuntu.
- Add another hard disk to your system, install Ubuntu on it and set your system to boot from it; you can choose to boot Windows or Ubuntu from the GRUB menu at startup
- Keep the disk as is, and run Ubuntu in a virtual machine, such as Virtualbox or VMWare Player.

Answer (score 4):

The best way to install Ubuntu is on a separate partition in dual boot with your Windows system.  My experience over several installations: after a while nobody still uses Windows OS. The only extra to do: with Gparted make a ext4 partition on your PC, and install ubuntu on that partition.  Thanks to grub you will be able to dual boot.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem too. After days of research, I found that there may have been a complication with the type of hard disk you're using. If it's dynamic, it won't work.

To check that, go to Disk Management by looking for it in the Start Menu if you use Windows  7, or type devmgmt in the Run utility in XP. Look under Disk 0 - that should be your boot device. If it's dynamic, you've got a huge problem at hand. 
Try right clicking on the word Disk 0. If the option "Convert to basic disk" is available, you're lucky. Go ahead and click it!

If not, try this link: http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/change-dynamic-disk-basic-without-losing-data-t1481159.html. I haven't tried it myself, but hopefully it might work.
Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can put an Ubuntu iso image on a bootable flash drive, using pendrive software http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows. You have to get your pc to boot from usb in your bios. Bios is obtained when you first turn on Windows 7. The instructions on the black screen at start up.

You can also use wubi to install up to 30GB of Ubuntu directly from your Windows7 http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/windows-installer  You have to create a wubi shortcut, and run the install from the shortcut.

You can mount the Ubuntu iso image, and install

Answer (score -1):

I am not expert , but I think you have Firewall or antivirus that prevent to execute command,

Also you might find this link useful rather than windows installer (wubi.exe).
http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2012/05/17/how-to-dual-boot-ubuntu-12-04-and-windows-7/

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with Firewall, but yes, disabling Antivirus sounds like a possible option.

Comment: In my experice, some firewall really prevent some functions, like "Zonealarm free firewall", it has trusted-zone which is may prevent some functions like act as a server like.

Comment: I do not use any kind of antivirus programs. I have only windows' firewall. However it is also blocked. Therefore I do not think that my problem is related to a firewall issue.