# unable to install ubuntu 12.04 on windows 7

Tags: 12.04, wubi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why can't I install Ubuntu or Wubi on a dynamic disk? (“The request isn't supported” from bcdedit.exe)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/179215/why-cant-i-install-ubuntu-or-wubi-on-a-dynamic-disk-the-request-isnt-suppor)

An error occurred:

```
Error executing command
command=C:/windows/system32/bcdedit.exe/set{aaf19def-e9a5-11e1-86de-9f7ceafcb45f} device partion=D:
..retval=1
..stderr=An error has occurred setting the element data.
The request is not supported.

..stdout=
```

For more information, please see the log file: `C/users/admin/appdata/local/tem/wubi-12.04-rev265.log`

Please help me solve the problem.

Comment: Please explain in a bit more depth what were you trying to do. Using a WUBI installer or something else? At what point during the installation did you get this error? Also, you can attach the mentioned log file.

Answer (score 0):

Please install as boot, First try ubuntu. If it works properly you can install it. If no, may be your hard has not a good partition. you have to format all and change it to 3part only while installing.