# Ubuntu 12.10 installation Problem in Wubi

Tags: wubi, 12.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why can’t I install Ubuntu or Wubi on a dynamic disk? (“The request isn’t supported” from bcdedit.exe)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/179215/why-cant-i-install-ubuntu-or-wubi-on-a-dynamic-disk-the-request-isnt-suppor)

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 12.10 on drive "I:\" along my Windows 7 with Wubi. But I got the following error message:

```
Error executing command
>>command=C:\Windows\System32\bcdedit.exe/set
{0bfbf1c0-11ba-11e2-a8ef-fooae3684131}device partition=I;
>>retval=1;
>>stdrr=An error has occured setting the element data.
the request is not supported.

>>stdout=
For more information,please see the log file;
c:\users\hammer~1\appdata\local\temp\wubi-12.10-rev273.log
```

What should I do now ?

@ https://askubuntu.com/users/5592/agmenor is too large for this content area(Exceeds limit). And the the "bcbc" link is same to my problem.But I can't fix it till now.
Any suggestion please ?

Comment: Welcome on Ask Ubuntu, HammerEngineer ! Could you please post the content of the file "C:\users\hammer~1\appdata\local\temp\wubi-12.10-rev273.log", by editing your question ? Also, could you please check whether the question linked by bcbc is a duplicate of yours ?

Comment: In a recent edit, OP has confirmed that both question is same.