# Getting an error while using Wubi installing

Tags: installation, wubi, 12.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why can’t I install Ubuntu or Wubi on a dynamic disk? (“The request isn’t supported” from bcdedit.exe)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/179215/why-cant-i-install-ubuntu-or-wubi-on-a-dynamic-disk-the-request-isnt-suppor)

I'm getting the error below while using Wubi to install Ubuntu 12.10 on Windows 7 Premium. I tried running Wubi as an admin and got the same error. I can't find an answer anywhere to this anywhere. Please help me!

```
Error executing command
>>command=C:\Windows\sysnative\bcdedit.exe/set
{95947f39-17a0-11e1-87c9-f358cae1eaf9}device partition=D:
>>retval=1
>>stderr=An error has occurred setting the element data.
The request is not supported.
```

Comment: Welcome on Ask Ubuntu, Michael ! Why did you use the "partitioning" tag ? Wubi doesn't need you to partition your disk, if I remember correctly. Also, please check bcbc's link to see whether your question is a duplicate one.

Comment: Yes my question is a duplicate one, sorry about that.