# Xubuntu installation using Wubi fails

Tags: installation

I'm trying to install Xubuntu using Wubi, however, once I start the installer, it runs all the way through (on the Installing Ubuntu-12.10amd 64 page with the two loading bars), and it gets to "Remaining time approximately 0s". Then, it gives me an error in a message box:

AN error occured:
Error executing command

> > command+C:\windows\sysnative\bcdedit.exe/set
> >     {a687fade-abcc-11e1-8095-e09fff5d0ff}device partiton=E:
> >     retval=1
> >     stderr=an error has occured setting......
> >     stdout=.......

Comment: i didnt understand the solutuion that u gave "web-E"

Comment: your disk type configuration is dynamic. This configuration only supported by windows. To able to install ubuntu (or any linux), your disk must of type `basic`. See the [difference](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/understand-the-differences-between-basic-disks-and-dynamic-disks/5797060). Here is a guide to perform the [conversion](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/26829-convert-dynamic-disk-basic-disk.html). But if you have created partition in these disks, you must delete them. **So take backup first**

Comment: The answers of that question also tells the same story.. http://askubuntu.com/a/179309/35775

Comment: if i convert my disk to basic will there any problem arise to my disk imean my disk would remain or it cleaned up the data???

Comment: if you created partition, answer is YES you need to wipe out the partition and data. If you don't want that, run ubuntu using virtualbox.