# Partitions created in Windows are not showing in Ubuntu

Tags: installation, dual-boot, partitioning, windows-8

I want to install Ubuntu 12.10 64 bit alongside Windows 8, so I created some free space in Windows 8.

When I try to install Ubuntu using a Live USB, the free space created is not visible and the partitions shown are completely different.

But when I click the option "Try Ubuntu", I am able to use my Windows partitions.

Comment: Boot ubuntu live-disk and click on try ubuntu to open gparted partition editor.Take screenshot of it and then upload the screenshot to imgur.com and provide the link here.

Comment: @Takkat Does free space belong to dynamic disk?If so, what is the solution for this?

Comment: @Takkat Ya. You were right. Dynamic disks were the problem.I installed AOMEI Partition manager to change disks to basic.Then the problem solved.If anyone has a similar problem,install AOMEI partition manager and change.Thank you for your valuable comments

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why can't I install Ubuntu or Wubi on a Windows Dynamic Disk?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/179215/why-cant-i-install-ubuntu-or-wubi-on-a-windows-dynamic-disk)

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu does not support Windows-specific "dynamic" disks. This may be one reason for partitions not showing up on installing Ubuntu or when partitioning a drive from Ubuntu.

> Before we partition a drive on Ubuntu we therefore have to change the partitions type from "dynamic" to "basic".

Obviously this can only be done from Windows (see [Window Server Support](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755238.aspx) and [Microsoft Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/354e5163-f388-4354-984c-ea4e4206694c)), e.g. with a partitioning tool (e.g. [AOMEI Partition Assistant](http://www.aomeitech.com/aomei-partition-assistant.html)).