# How Do I Install Ubuntu 14.04 With Self Installed Windows 8?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I'm really screwed. I'm trying to hit the job from 2 hours myself but can't figure out what's wrong. Followed youtube, askubuntu as well, but no luck. First of all, what I'm trying to do is:

- I want to install Ubuntu 14.04 (Latest release till 10/21/14) to dual boot with my existing Windows 8 (64-bit) Operating System.

I've created myself a bootable USB stick and come good to the partition section of ubuntu install. But here's when things mess. I don't know how do I split partition here. First of all, check that my secure boot is disabled as I'm the one who installed everything on this PC (even OS):

WINDOWS CONFIG:

[image]

And Now, what appears when I install Ubuntu:

[image]

[image]

How to solve it ?

Comment: Are your partitions [dynamic disks](http://askubuntu.com/questions/409561/partitions-created-in-windows-are-not-showing-in-ubuntu) or encrypted?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be on the right track, but you'll need to [create some free space](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot#Manual_partitioning) for Ubuntu on your drive(s). To achieve that,

1. select “something else“ as installation type to manually partition your drive(s),
2. select the partition(s) you want to shrink and press “change“,
3. enter the desired new partition size,
4. press + to add one ore more partitions for Ubuntu,
5. press “install now”.

If you feel more comfortable with other partition managers (in Windows) or if step 3 doesn't work as described, you can use those other partition managers to prepare the Ubuntu installation and shrink partitions. Even Windows Disk Manager will let you shrink partitions. Another option is GParted which you can run, if you choose to “Try Ubuntu“ before installation.