# Can't install ubuntu 16.04 alongside windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I've defragmented my C drive and shrank it to get a free space of 40 GB.

Screenshot of my Disk Manager:

[image]

And I've disabled fast book and restarted by PC to boot from USB.When the Ubuntu installation begins, there is no option for installing Ubuntu alongside windows 10.
If I choose 'something else' here's what I get:

Ubuntu installation screen-shot:

[image]
[image]

Can anyone please tell me where to go from here?

Comment: Dynamic partitions are your problem.  The installer cannot handle them. Conversion is possible, search a bit, various problems can occur.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't I install Ubuntu or Wubi on a Windows Dynamic Disk?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/179215/why-cant-i-install-ubuntu-or-wubi-on-a-windows-dynamic-disk)

Answer (score 0):

hey there let me help you by looking at your screen shots it means that:

1. you have 4 partitions 2 with ntfs in which one has windows 10 boot loader
2. now go ahead with the second screenshot select /dev/sda4 and install (/) of ubuntu on it and in the below you will have

Device for boot loader installation:
then select /dev/sda

thats it you are done.
next time you boot you will get a menu to dual boot.

Answer (score 0):

okey so your problem is with partition table and no of primary partitions you have. As you may not know that whenever you try to make more than 4 primary partitions using installation it says "system can only support 4 logical partition"if i quote right. Guess what we have here, 5 primary partitions and 1 allocated space.