# dual boot Ubuntu with Windows 10 (already having 4 important dynamic partitions)

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation

I have HP g6 laptop with Windows 10 installed having partitions as follows:

[image: disk partition]

As you can see, there are already 4 partitions (which I cannot delete) + 1 partition (F: which has data). I am aware that these partitions are of the dynamic type and therefore, Ubuntu cannot be installed on a separate partition.

I tried creating unallocated space of 70 GB from F: but Ubuntu setup was not able to detect 70 GB partition (maybe since the drive is of dynamic type).

What would be the **best approach** if I want to install Ubuntu with Windows 10 without disturbing the current Windows 10 installation?

In other words, I want to have at least 3 partitions (one for Windows, one for Ubuntu and one for storing data) without affecting other things.

Comment: Shouldn't most of those `MB` really be `GB`?

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the mistakes. I have corrected it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't I install Ubuntu or Wubi on a Windows Dynamic Disk?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/179215/why-cant-i-install-ubuntu-or-wubi-on-a-windows-dynamic-disk) and [How to resize partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/)

Comment: Also: https://askubuntu.com/questions/482768/changing-windows-dynamic-disk-partition-to-basic-partition-and-not-the-full-driv & https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2325331&p=13492758&viewfull=1#post13492758