# 18.04 LTS: How to take disk space from Windows 10 and use it to install Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, partitioning, system-installation, windows-10

I have Windows 10 Home.There are:-
1- C: 83.86 GB (where windows is installed)
2- D: 16.34 GB (where recovery is stored)
3- F: 244.14 GB (where personal data stored e.g. songs,videos,softwares)
4- G: 244.14 GB (where movies are stored)
5- H: 341.8 GB (where i want to install Ubuntu 18.04 LTS)
So how to dual boot and install Ubuntu 18.04 in H: where i have 341.8 GB ?

Comment: You cannot install to H: as if seen as H: it is NTFS. Linux needs LInux format often ext4. Install will erase H. Post list of all partitions from live installer' terminal above to preserve format. `sudo parted -l`. If UEFI install, you must install Ubuntu in UEFI boot mode.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI
Also shows Windows 10 screens or similar to Windows 8
https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-10-with-uefi You may want smaller / (root) partition of about 30GB and rest as /home. Default install will make it all as / (root).

Answer (score 0):

First, while still in Windows, right click on the [START] button of Windows (the Windows icon at far bottom left) and choose Disk Management. Find your H: drive; you will need to know which physical drive it is on and [which partition it is](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/i386/apcs04.html).

Also, confirm by looking in the columns Layout and Type that it is a Basic Disk Type with Simple Layout and not a [Dynamic Disk](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/basic-and-dynamic-disks), because [Linux can't use a Dynamic Disk](https://askubuntu.com/questions/179215/why-cant-i-install-ubuntu-or-wubi-on-a-windows-dynamic-disk).

[image: Screenshot from Disk Management]

Once you've done that, while you are still in Disk Management, delete the H: drive partition, and make note of the physical drive it was on from the Volume column.

Download the ISO file for the version of your choice from https://ubuntu.com/download or for a 'flavour' with a different Desktop Environment, download from https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours .

The ISO file you use to create a LiveUSB should be [checked for download errors](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0).

Creating the LiveUSB, as per Ubuntu's publishers, is typically done following these instructions on either [another Linux PC](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#0)  or on a [Windows PC](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#0) .

Once you make a LiveUSB, boot with it, after shutting Windows down completely (no Sleep, no Hibernate) by clicking on the Windows START icon at bottom far left, hold down the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key, and while holding it down, choose **Shutdown**. Power up after Shutdown and, using the Boot Order key of your computer (which varies according to make and model), boot from that LiveUSB.

[Follow these steps](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#0), but when you get to [6. Allocate Drive Space](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#5), find the space on your drive(s) previously used for H:, and then choose to install Ubuntu in there.

Comment: What  do you mean by **find the space on your drive(s) previously used for H:, and then choose to install Ubuntu in there.** ? <br/> Which option to choose to find the space?

Comment: Look in the Volume column. See screenshot added above and read https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-open-disk-management-2626080